# AngularJS ui-router update template state on error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to replace the template of a state when the resolve promise catch an error, any way to do that?

For example:

```
.state('mystate', {
    url:'/mystate',
    resolve: {
        myObject: function($http) {
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/mystateurl'});
        }
    },
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/template.html',
            controller: 'CustomController'
        }
    }
})
```

This state use a custom template 'partials/template.html', i want to change the value of the template when the resolve method is an http 404 (or 500, etc), the goal is to display an error template with the right location/url, actually, if a resolve catch an error, the location is not updated.

That's not the real attempt of a browser, you call a resource so you update the url, then the page display the error.

Thanks in advance for your help.